# Flutter app keeps printing [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]

Tags: flutter

Hello my app keeps printing this line even though there is no error in the app and it works fine

```
[ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
```

it prints more than 50 each minute . and only in two screens that it starts to print this .

Comment: I see the same error message with my app, and I use Java/Android Studio, without the Flutter framework installed. However, I'm using a Huawei P20 lite for testing, and see more weird and (in my opinion) irrelevant error and warning messages, which however do not seem to influence performance in any way. Could it be you are using the same brand? I've been searching the web for those messages, and they often seem to be related to Huawei/Honor.

Answer (score 9):

that's the Huawei/Honor Issue. if you change the device this message will disappear.
same thing is happening with me but after some digging I found that Huawei added something, so that's why you are seeing this.

**UPDATE**

Now the new Update of VSCode is grouping all the messages that are the same and put them in one line and increase the number of these messages

that is helping much while doing debugging

Comment: how to mitigate that

Comment: I searched a lot about it but unfortunately I could not event reach any solution yet @Bawantha

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, you can try to fold the same logs as following:

- right click on the log saying `[ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]`
- then click on **Fold lines like this** as the following image

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce8Bd.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same. I discovered I was falling in an endless loop creating HttpServers. Solved the loop, solved the problem. Hope, that helps.

Comment: can you please explain more about this issue ?

Comment: but even with apps that contains no http calls yet we are facing the same issue